# bilibop-lockfs is disabled

Tags: filesystem, etc

when starting my machine I got this message:

**bilibop-lockfs is disabled**

How to enable it  ?

[image: bilibop-lockfs is disabled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only single user of this computer, then it is unexpected to have `bilibop-lockfs` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bilibop-lockfs) installed. Its purpose is "lock filesystems and write changes into RAM".

So you probably have to remove this package by

```
sudo apt-get purge --autoremove bilibop-lockfs
```

and then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Edit "/etc/bilibop/bilibop.conf" file and add the following: **BILIBOP_LOCKFS="true"** line and then save > exit > reboot.

But,
**to disable it** again you will have to use live environment and edit the same file above but this time you will add "#" symbol IN-FRONT of the line you added previously like so... **#BILIBOP_LOCKFS="true"**

You welcome !